# Where are Adobe Flash cookies (sol files) stored?

Tags: flash, adobe

Adobe Flash cookies (files with `.sol` extension) used to be located in `~/.macromedia`. This folder no longer exists in Ubuntu 14.04LTS and newer. If the method of installing Flash has any effect on the location, the Ubuntu Installer option is how I installed it. So where are the Flash Cookies now located? I've tried searching for `.sol` files with no luck - and yes I have "Show Hidden Files" enabled in File Manager. Does anyone know where they're stored now?

Comment: I have a  ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player folder with in it dirs macromedia.com  and #SharedObjects settings.sol is inside ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys and serveral other sub-dirs :)

Comment: Someone want to hack their savegame file?

Comment: Maybe to backup Flash Game savefiles. Too bad adobe doesn't provide a backup utility by itself.

Answer (score 7):

If you checked the *"Install this third party software"* option during Ubuntu installation process, you're using [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) *Adobe Flash* plugin installed through [flashplugin-installer](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree) package. The same plugin is provided by [adobe-flashplugin](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin) package from Canonical Partner repo as well. This is the plugin generally used by **Firefox** and all other browsers not based on *Chromium*. In this case, the cookies are stored at:

```
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/
```

---

**Google Chrome** bundles a [Pepper Plugin API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client#Pepper) (PPAPI) based Flash plugin. For this plugin, the `.sol` files are stored at:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/
```

If you use the PPAPI Flash plugin on other *Chromium* based browsers, replace `google-chrome` in the path given above with name of your browser. For example, with **Chromium**:

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/
```

---

Tested on *Adobe Flash* 21.0 PPAPI and 11.2 NPAPI plugins.

Source : [Wikipedia page on Local Shared Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object#File_locations)
Thanks to [Xen2050](https://askubuntu.com/users/129271/xen2050) for providing info about Flash plugin on *Chromium*!

Comment: Chromium stores it's files in `~/.config/chromium/...` otherwise looks the same as for Chrome

Comment: @Xen2050 Thanx for the info on *Chromium*!   I just updated the answer to cover _Chromium_ too! 

Answer (score 1):

There is the ~/.macromedia folder in 11.04. Your flash cookies are located in **~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys** directory.

There is another way to see your flash cookies and make whatever you want with them  in the [Global Storage Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html) from the Adobe Flash Player Website.

Also, if you want to find out more about flash cookies, there are many things to know about them [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/04/flash-cookies-explained/).

Comment: Often, both the `.macromedia` and `.adobe` folders exist (even on systems that have only ever had one version of Flash installed). So it's worth looking in both folders. If you want to clear locally cached Flash data and Flash cookies, you can delete both folders.

Answer (score 1):

Type this in terminal:
locate *.sol

Or to remove all flash cookies:

```
rm `locate *.sol`
```

Note that locate isn't updated very fast, so if you run `locate *.sol` again after removing them. It'll indicate that the files still exists. Try to remove them again, an you'll get a couple of messages indicating that the files do not exist anymore.
This method is fairly reliable, but won't remove very fresh flash cookies, since they haven't been indexed yet, and so 'locate' doesn't know about them yet.

Comment: I don't use `locate` or `updatedb`, so the `locate *.sol` command does not find any of my .sol files. `find` would be a much better command to find currently existing files

Answer (score 0):

If you download and install a flash game on your computer, you can find it in:

```
Home/.wine/drive_c/user/"User name"/Application Data/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/"some random code?"/localhost/Downloads/...
```

hope it useful